# Get the row number in R given the row name

Tags: r

Is there an equivalent "match" function for the rows?

I could use:

```
which(rownames(data.frame)=="name")
```

but since

```
which(colnames(data.frame)=="name")
```

can be replaced by

```
match("name", names(data.frame))
```

I wonder if there is a similar function for the rows. My goal is to delete rows directly using their names, not their number.

Thanks

Stéphane

Comment: [Make your question reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1315767) and consider using `%in%`

Comment: Why do you not want to use their row numbers?

Comment: `match("name",rownames(data.frame))`